# How to parse data of a certain user in firebase? | React Native

Tags: react-native

How to parse data of a certain user in firebase . I use React Native Expo

I think fetchData () should be used.But I don't know exactly how to do that.

Comment: Can you share any information or better yet a code? any of your attempts? doing that would really help us resolve your problem. What's a sample format of the data you are trying to parse?

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply.

If to be specific I need to parse data which are on this way:
.ref("users/" + this.state.nameCheckVK + "/events/" }

All that is in /events/